# How do I fix my reddit comment sorting?

Tags: reddit

I recently somehow messed up my reddit sorting. By default when I open a thread, it sorts by new, not top. I prefer to see Top, but cannot figure out how I can revert this change. I have looked through all of the RES settings, and changed a few (that did nothing and I reverted them) that I thought might work.

Can someone please help me? I can't think of anywhere else to ask this.

Answer (score 1):

**In Comment Threads**

In any reddit comment thread, you have the option to change your comment sorting options via a drop-down menu immediately under the 'top X comments' header.

Here's a screenshot from /r/worldnews with RES enabled, where I've enabled the 'sorted by' drop-down menu:

[image: A screenshot from /r/worldnews with Reddit Enhancement Suite and the 'sorted by' drop-down menu for comment sorting enabled.]

Simply click the down arrow next to 'sorted by: *option*' to view the drop-down menu.  You can select sort by top from here.

**In Site Preferences**

If that doesn't do the trick, you may have accidentally toggled it in your site-wide preferences.  Visit https://www.reddit.com/prefs/ to check:

[image: Reddit preferences, showing comment sorting preferences.]